# Select arrow do not appear on iphone

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Looking for a solution for a problem I'm having.

I am making a responsive website that has a select tag to allow users to pick which category of blog posts they want to display the html is just a basic select tag.

```
<select name="">
    <option value="">Sort by Category</option>
    <option value="">test</option>
    <option value="">Test</option>
</select>
```

I then have styled the select tag with the following code

```
.portfolio-thumbs select {
    width:100%;
    padding:0.625em;
    border:none;
    background:#33c3e2;
    color:#fff; 
    font-size:1.125em;
 }

select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

This works fine on Windows phone but on Iphone, Blackberry and Android the arrow for the select box does not display. Has anyone encountered this problem before and know what i am doing in my CSS to disable the arrow from displaying or have a solution to get the arrow back whilst still being able to style the select how i want.

Comment: Select boxes cause a lot of pain. In the past I've tried using JQuery Mobile select box (ugly, rounded, and butchers the DOM) and Bootstrap select box. Still not 100% convinced of the nicest way. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11186039/1061602

Comment: try removing -webkit-appearance

Comment: remove the webkit-appearance? that's causing the problem perhaps.

Comment: I know that -webkit-appearance appearance is most likely cause of the problem but removing it will mean i no longer have any real control of the select boxs style which id like to try and keep if its impossible though then thats the root i will have to go down

Comment: you can try dropkick, it's a pretty easy to use dropdown customizer.  I wouldn't waste time with this stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-webkit-appearance: none;` line is telling webkit browsers (iPhone, BB and 'droid) to not display the default `<select>` appearance. Removing this line will restore the arrow.

As mentioned in the comments, `<select>` is a real pain to style. The only realistic option if you want real control of how it looks it to use a replacement technique as mentioned by @AdamMarshal.

Alternatively, if you absolutely must use a `<select>` and `-webkit-appearance: none;`, add a background image of an arrow.

Comment: Not a absolute must and the problem with background image is that on browsers like Firefox and Ie the background image would display under the arrow so i have decided to go down the jQuery replacement route

Comment: Wow, I hope a css solution comes around soon for this in the future

Answer (score 1):

In my case, `appearance` was already set to `auto`. What I found was setting any `background-color` made the arrow appear for iOS > Web [Chrome, Safari].

So, I hacked together a fix using `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.01)`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to select element and define "-webkit-appearance: auto" or "-webkit-appearance: initial" - this will also override user agent stylesheet (default browser's value for webkit appearance)