# How would I place a font-awesome icon into a select drop-down menu?

Tags: html, css, select, font-awesome

I've been battling with trying to place a font-awesome icon into a select option (drop down menu). I have tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837657/is-it-possible-to-use-font-awesome-icon-instead-to-select-default-drop-down-sign) that was posted on this site. However, this places the font-awesome icon next to the label and not within the select option box.

I've also tried putting in the unicode directly into the html option tag... however, once clicked on that down arrow it turns into a question mark. (Also, I cannot use bootstrap with this project)

Please help!

HTML:

```
<div class="modal-form stack col75">
    <label for="game">Game:</label>
    <select class="form-control easy-drop-down" id="modal-game-options"> 
        <option selected disabled>Please Select a Show</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
select {
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  -o-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: white;
  padding-left: 20px;
  content: "&#xf107;";
}
```

**Here are some snapshots**

Current:
    [without-arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RidrF.png)

Goal:
    [with-arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWGg9.png)

Comment: It's pretty hard to implement something like this consistently across browsers with a `<select>` element.  Are you wanting to use this as part of a form, and the `<select>` element is required, or are you wanting to show a list of options when clicking on a button?  Something structured more like this: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns may be much more suitable if you aren't using it as part of an HTML form.

Answer (score 1):

What you made wrong that the link actually does:

1- The label doesn't end before the select, it ends after.

2- The label is used to generate the font-awesome icon with the content trough the after sub selection.

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal-form stack col75">
    <label for="game">Game:
    <select class="form-control easy-drop-down" id="modal-game-options"> 
        <option selected disabled>Please Select a Show</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
    </select>
    </label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
select {
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  -o-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: white;
  width: 175px;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    select {padding-right:18px}
}

label {position:relative}
label:after {
    content:"\f078";   
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    font-size: 11px;
    color:#aaa;
    right:8px; top:3px;
    padding:0 0 1px;
    position:absolute;
    pointer-events:none;
}
label:before {
    content:'';
    right:4px; top:0px;
    width:20px; height:16px;
    background:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    pointer-events:none;
    display:block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/01b9Lh1g/

Answer (score 0):

i tried your code by removing the  "selected disabled" from the first option tag.it worked perfectly for me.

```
<div class="modal-form stack col75">
    <label for="game">Game:</label>
    <select class="form-control easy-drop-down" id="modal-game-options"> 
        <option >Please Select a Show</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: The 'selected disable' doesn't make a difference if it's there or not for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code. You should try this.

HTML code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<label>
    <select id="international"> 
        <option value="tests" selected="selected">Select Option</option>
        <option value="tests.au">Option 1</option>
        <option value="tests.br/">Option 2</option>
        <option value="tests">Option 3</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

***CSS Script***

```
<style>
select {
    padding:4px;
    margin: 0;
    background: #fff;
    color:#888;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    width: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

/* Targetting Webkit browsers only. FF will show the dropdown arrow with so much padding. */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    select {padding-right:18px}
}

label {position:relative}
label:after {
    content:"\f078";   
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    font-size: 11px;
    color:#aaa;
    right:8px; top:4px;
    padding:0 0 2px;
    position:absolute;
    pointer-events:none;
}
label:before {
    content:'';
    right:4px; top:0px;
    width:23px; height:18px;
    background:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    pointer-events:none;
    display:block;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use bootstrap in this :(

Comment: Plus that solution puts the arrow next to the label not in the select box itself (I provided a link to this solution in my question description)

Answer (score 0):

i have made some changes to @ DarkHyudrA'sanswer..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
select {
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  -o-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: white; padding:8px 10px; border-radius:2px; border:#ADD8E6 solid 1px; 
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    select {padding-right:35px}
}

label {position:relative}
label:after {
    content:"\f078";   
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    font-size: 10px;
    color:#aaa;
    right:10px; top:3px;
    padding:0 0 1px;
    position:absolute;
    pointer-events:none;
}
label:before {
    content:'';
    right:4px; top:0px;
    width:20px; height:16px;
    background:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    pointer-events:none;
    display:block;
}
</style>


<div class="modal-form stack col75">
<div class="modal-form stack col75">
    <label for="game">Game:
    <select class="form-control easy-drop-down" id="modal-game-options"> 
        <option selected disabled>Please Select a Show</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
    </select>
    </label>
</div>
</div>
```

here is th fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/cnaysvc5/