# Custom HTML Select Arrow Image

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I want to hide the defalut arrow of the html select list and add a custom image(arrow) to  the list.

[image: See the Picture]

```
.form-inline select {
            margin: 10px 35px 15px 0px;
            background-color: #fff;
            font-size: 30px;
            width: 80px;
            color: #000;
            background-image: url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/down4-512.png") center bottom no-repeat;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block;
            outline: none;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
            border: none !important;
            justify-content:center;
            align-items:center;
            text-align:center;
        }
```

this is my current styles . It is not displaying the arrow as I want. Please help me out.

Comment: There is a background-image property in your css, search for the image that you want and replace it, that's all.

Comment: it is not working pal. thats why I seek help

Comment: Maybe you can't hotlink the image and you need to download it and use it from your own project folder.

Comment: not working I tried

Comment: Please edit question and add your HTML code and what have you tried.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [replacing <select> aroow with a custom image and make it open dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27324050/replacing-select-aroow-with-a-custom-image-and-make-it-open-dropdown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing `background` and `background-image` CSS styling together, no wonder your styling doesn't work:

Short version: (I'm using `background` instead of `background-image`)

```
background: salmon url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/down4-512.png") no-repeat center calc(100% - 2px);
background-size: 24px 24px;
```

But I recommend this way for easier modification purpose:

```
background-color: #fff;
background-image: url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/down4-512.png");
background-size: 24px 24px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center calc(100% - 2px);
```

FYI, this CSS part will hide the default arrow of browser:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
```